# A question regarding the ways of writing even numbers as the sum of two numbers

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How can we prove that $\forall n\in\Bbb N$, $\exists a,b:a+b=2n:a,b\not\equiv 0\pmod {2,3}$?

Such a thing, I regard to be definitely true, but thinking about it, I could not find an way of proving such a thing.

Comment: This is a hair short of asking whether the Goldbach conjecture is true. If $a,b\not \equiv 0 (\bmod 2,3)$ then $a,b \equiv -1,1 (\bmod 6)$. The question asks whether even numbers can be expressed as the sum of two numbers of the form $6n-1,\ 6m+1$, which form includes all primes numbers other than $2,3$ (and many composite numbers as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$n=2$ is problematic, no?

For $n≥3$ we work by cases:

If $2n=3k$ then $1, 2n-1$ will work.

If $2n=3k+1$ then $5, 2n-5$ will work.

If $2n=3k+2$ then $1, 2n-1$ will work.

Comment: Why does $n=2$ is problematic? doesn't $a=b=1$ work?

Comment: @infinity  No, since the OP is trying to get the sum $2n=4$.  Your only options would be $4=1+3=2+2$ and neither work.  I am assuming that natural numbers were desired, of course, though this is not stated in the problem.